Cassandra 4.1.2 - nodetool describecluster shows unreachable:0 but nodes are unreachable
We had an incident on one of our 4.1.2 cassandra productionn instances whereby nodetool status showed all instances as UN (on affected and stable instances). But running nodetool describecluster on the affected instance showed Unreachable: 0 under "Stats for all nodes" but all other instances were listed as UNREACHABLE under "schema versions".
Likewise running nodetool describecluster on a stable instance showed the affected instance as UNREACHABLE under "schema versions" but Unreachable: 0 under "Stats for all nodes".
Any idea under what circumstances could this happen?
